# How to load a local file using Stream in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm running windows and am trying to load a local file (given the file path) in C#. I want the type of the read file to be `System.IO.Stream`.

I tried using `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Path_To_File.csv")` but it didn't work..

What method in C# will do this?

Comment: What "didn't work" means? Did it explicitly return "I DON'T WORK" with bold red letters across your screen or what?

Comment: What code do you *want* to work? Does the `BaseStream` property not work?

Comment: Did you escape the backslashes in the path correctly? (Use a verbatim string)

Comment: `string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();`

Answer (score 7):

What you want is File.OpenRead()

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path)) 
{
    ...
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)